# Libgdx how to stop files being saved to /storage/emulated/0/ on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on a libgdx project and I can't get my save function to work correctly.

```
String levelstr = String.valueOf(levelNum); 
FileHandle publicFile = Gdx.files.external("SkippyRocketMaps/level"+levelstr+".tmx");
String tmap = "a lot of data";
publicFile.writeString(tmap, false);
```

This code overwrites files in that location, but when I try to create a new file it doesn't.
For new files it appears to be saving it into "/storage/emulated/0/SkippyRocketMaps/level"+levelstr+".tmx" which I cannot access. I need to be able to view and edit the files from my computer with a USB connection.
Also my android manifest includes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and my Android launcher includes

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //the read request isn't showing up
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 201); //WRITE_REQUEST_CODE
                //this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 200); //READ_REQUEST_CODE
                //this.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUESTP);
            }
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 200); //WRITE_REQUEST_CODE
            }
        }
```

Edit: after some research I think the /storage/emulated/0/ folder is supposed to copy itself over to the folder I can access. I think the issue may be with the phone itself and not my code. Also I found another nuance, when I overwrite the older files it only works sometimes. Sometimes if I add more data to the file it won't save all of the new data. It seems to cut off the text after a certain length. It makes me think the phone hasn't allocated enough space for the file. Hopefully I'll get access to a new phone soon so I can see if my phone is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp I found the answer to my own question. The /storage/emulated/0/ folder is supposed to copy itself over to the folder I can access. There was something wrong with my old phone and it wasn't copying it over properly. I got a new phone and my save function is now working correctly.